# Fernet Invalid Token Error for Password Manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, encryption, cryptography

I am currently trying to make a custom little password manager in Python using the cryptography module. Encryption with a master password seems okay, but decrypting it results in 2 errors:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import os
import base64
import pickle
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

logins = {}
masterpass = bytes(input('Unlock login ring with master password: '), 'utf-8')

def newLogin(email, username, password):
    logins['{}:{}'.format(email, username)] = password

def loadLogins():
    salt = os.urandom(16)
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(masterpass))

    f = Fernet(key)

    file = open('keyring.keys', 'rb')

    token = f.decrypt(file.read())

    print(file.read())

    file.close()
    

def saveLogins():
    salt = os.urandom(16)
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(masterpass))

    f = Fernet(key)

    logs = ['{}'.format(x) for x in logins]
    pasw = ['{}'.format(logins[y]) for y in logins]

    keys = []

    for i in range(len(logins)):
        keys += logs[i] + ':' + pasw[i] + ';'

    print(''.join(keys))

    keyring = f.encrypt(bytes(''.join(keys), 'utf-8'))

    file = open('keyring.keys', 'wb')

    pickle.dump(keyring, file)

    file.close()
```

The way my code works is you have to give it a master password initially. It will then store that master password as a bytes object. Next, you can add/update logins to the logins dictionary. Then, using the Fernet recipe for passwords ([Using passwords with Fernet (cryptography module)](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#using-passwords-with-fernet)), I convert the master password into a Fernet key for encrypting and decrypting the logins to and from a file. As stated above, the encryption works fine, but decryption always results in an error. Am I doing something wrong with my decryption function? Or how I implement the password encryption/decryption?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, stupid mistakes where made. The solution was to generate an os.urandom salt and use that as a literal (aka "magic number") for the derivation of the key. Also, I just need to derive the key only once, not in every function.

I also need to call pickle.load on the file I am going to write to. Here is a working solution:

```
import base64
import pickle
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

logins = {}
masterpass = bytes(input('Unlock login ring with master password: '), 'utf-8')

# Derive key from master password
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=b'\xaab\xc0\xe0+\xc8\xb29\xc5\xe9\xbb\xfb\xaa\xb6\xab\xa7',
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)

key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(masterpass))

f = Fernet(key)


# Add or update login information in
# the logins dictionary.
def setLogin(website, email, username, password):
    logins[website] = '{}:{}:{}'.format(email, username, password)


# Load and decrypt the logins and
# return them in string format.
def loadLogins():
    file = open('keyring.keys', 'rb')

    token = f.decrypt( pickle.load(file) )

    file.close()

    return token.decode('utf-8')


# Separate and load logins into the
# logins dictionary.
def parseLogins(strLogins):
    individual_logins = strLogins.split(';')

    for i in range(len(individual_logins)):
        if (individual_logins[i] != ''):
            website, email, username, password = individual_logins[i].split(':')

            setLogin(website, email, username, password)
    
    print(individual_logins)


# Encrypt and save logins in a bytes file 
# using the master password.
def saveLogins():
    logs = ['{}'.format(x) for x in logins]
    pasw = ['{}'.format(logins[y]) for y in logins]

    keys = []

    for i in range(len(logins)):
        keys += logs[i] + ':' + pasw[i] + ';'

    print(''.join(keys))

    keyring = f.encrypt(bytes(''.join(keys), 'utf-8'))

    file = open('keyring.keys', 'wb')

    pickle.dump(keyring, file)

    print(keyring)

    file.close()


# Display all login information.
def showLogins():
    for i in logins:
        info = logins[i].split(':')
        
        website = i
        email = info[0]
        username = info[1]
        password = info[2]
        
        print(f'\nWebsite: {website}\nEmail: {email}\nUsername: {username}\nPassword: {password}\n')
```